# What Do You Call The Approach Being Used In This JavaScript Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

At my current place of work we have a set way of going about JavaScript and was wondering if someone can help shed any light on the below approach to storing variables and cached jQuery objects.

```
(function($) {

    var APP = {};

    $(function() {

        APP.header = $("#header");
        APP.footer = $("#footer");

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Firstly, what is the point of setting what appears to be a global variable and then appending jQuery objects to the variable? Does it keep things cleaner, does it make your app perform any faster or is it an easier way to set variables without having to go:

```
var header = $("#header");
var footer = $("#footer");
```

I understand everything else going on, but always wondered why this was common place in all our project JS files? I presume there is a name for what is going on here and I'd like to understand it a little better, especially if there are caveats that I should bring up with my manager about doing this.

Comment: It looks like just an easier way to keep up with globals while designing the rest of the site, however, this can lead to ALOT of mistakes, slower code (more files to load possibly depending on the setup), and even a lost global if one of these is "reset" somewhere else and forgotten.  It's a "clean read" practice, but not one "I'd" recommend.  But then i've only got a lifetime of experience, 0 schooling and a career in this for quite a while now, so my advice is "take it or leave it" ... i'm no proffesor, lol

Comment: @SpYk3HH When the application reaches a certain level of complexity, you need concise structures. Namespacing is a good way to do this. You won't become happy with every developer in your company using his own style of programming and own namingconventions and so on...

Comment: understandable, but still not best practice, would be better to have your tools set to use namespacing "styles" such as where I currently work, we have all of our komodo's setup with custom "toolbox's" that we can each add and edit so that everyone is always on the same page wether writing locally or globally.  I should add that the "custom toolbox" is shared across the network, not custom to each person

Comment: You raise a good point about accidentally resetting the global name-space variable, especially considering the APP name-space is responsible for holding everything.

Comment: Dwayne, in practice that never happens. I would not take @SpYk3HH's advice here, it's very bad advice. Global data variables have *way more* drawbacks than global namespace variables. Really both should be avoided as much as possible though. Decouple the components in your code and global variables and global namespaces both become bad practices.

Comment: On the one hand, this is true. But before ES5 - where you can freeze - every variable may be overridden, even `undefined` can be altered. That's the way how JS works(ed). But on the other hand it's easier to detect an override of you whole framework ( question: who should do that and why?), than one tiny variable being accidently altered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of these constructs are `closure` and `namespace`. A closure is a function that maintains references to variables outside of its scope.

Note that you can now access the `APP` variable later and it will be correctly updated:

```
(function($) {
    var APP = {};

    $(function() {
        APP.header = $("#header");
        APP.footer = $("#footer");
    });

    // "APP.header" and "APP.footer" are defined later in the code
})(jQuery);
```

If you used local variables, you could not get his effect:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var header = $("#header");
        var footer = $("#footer");
    });

    // "header" and "footer" are long gone local variables
})(jQuery);
```

Note that you *could* use global variables (technically properties of `window`) here:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        header = $("#header");
        footer = $("#footer");
    });

    // "header" and "footer" are accessible global variables
})(jQuery);
```

But that's bad practice for a number of reasons (notably, possible collisions and unexpectedly defined variables). So you set up what's called a namespace -- a variable like `APP` to hold your data that needs to be "global-like".

As to the specific utility of this closure in your case, note that it's surrounded by `$()`. This is a jQuery way of saying "run this functoin when the DOM has finished loading". The DOM has to be finished loading before trying to access `$('#header')` and `$('#footer')` to make sure these items actually exist in the DOM. But since this is a callback, it will be execute *later*, that's why it's need a closure to maintain a reference to `APP` when it does eventually get called.

Comment: Nice answer Ben. So really creating your own APP namespace variable is no different than binding to "window" except for the fact you won't get any clashes or accidentally overwrite a global variable. I understand the concept of namespaces. So there is no speed difference really binding to a namespaced variable than there is creating your own global variable, correct?

Comment: @Dwayne, any speed difference in either direction is negligible. This is purely for structural robusness.

Comment: @Dwayne If you are interested you can read about variable and function hoisting in javascript. With namespacing, you minimize the need for local variable declarations, which again minimizes memoryconsumption and errors due to hoisting.

Answer (score 1):

It's called namespacing.

This is so that you can keep the DOM clean, and other plugins/scripts won't interfere.  If you were to create a global var called header or footer, another plugin may want to use that global var, and thus breaking your code.

Answer (score 1):

`APP` appears to be the namespace your company uses to have an applicationwide consistent notation without cluttering the global namespace.

Also using variables to store the access to Dom-Elements is faster then accessing them each time needed via the jQuery Construct `$("...")`

Comment: So there is no performance advantage other than keeping the global namespace clean?

Comment: @Dwayne storing the access to dom-elements in variables has a performance gain, but namespacing on its own does not. However it helps greatly with huge applications. Look at jQuery. You have one namespace - `$` where you can access all the function you need.

Comment: Ah, of course. Very good point about the global jQuery variable.

Answer (score 0):

Other than my comment, some "caveats" to "Global Vars"

- Local variables are freed from memory whereas global vars sit with the lifetime of the app open
- If code is inside a function or in another scope and references that variable, the engine has to slow down to step back until it reaches your global scope, thus causing "lag"
- Little known factoid, global scope is shared with the window object!!!  This means it takes even LONGER for the engine to find them, thus another negative slow down point